# Rails: how do I unscope a uniq call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a relation where `uniq` has been called upon like:

```
rel = Car.where(brand: 'Audi').order(:price).uniq
```

Now I want to unscope the `uniq` (DISTINCT) part, so that I can do:

```
rel.limit(30).pluck(:id)
```

Since this will give me an error like:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

This is due to the query calling: `SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM cars WHERE brand = 'Audi' ORDER BY price` where I want it to do: `SELECT id FROM cars WHERE brand = 'Audi' ORDER BY price` - however I cannot figure out how to unstop the `DISTINCT` part only?

Comment: What is the purpose of `uniq` here? Why would your query return identical `id`s without the `uniq`?

Comment: The relation is dynamically created/scoped based on a lot of search criteria and passed on to this piece code, which needs to just pluck the first 30 id's matching the search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct(false)` to override the `uniq`:

```
rel = Car.where(brand: 'Audi').order(:price).uniq
rel.distinct(false).limit(30).pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Note: you can also call `distinct(nil)` if you're getting a structural incompatibility warning while trying to use `.or`. This has the same effect, but due to the way Rails detects structural incompatibilities it won't treat these the same. It detects structure incompatibilities by taking the `distinct` values from both queries, comparing them, and raising an error if they're different and since comparing `nil == false` returns `false` it treats these as incompatible even though they have the same effec.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just define another variable without uniq? If you're trying to get to

```
SELECT id FROM cars WHERE brand = 'Audi' ORDER BY price
```

Then I think

```
rel_2 = Car.where(brand: 'Audi').order(:price)
rel_2.pluck(:id)
```

Would do the trick

Comment: Because the relation is passed on as an argument from another place in the code, and it's pretty long and has a lot of scopes on it - which varies.